# PHP Dynamically fill array

Tags: php, arrays, parsing, csv

I have a large array of product data organized as:

```
Array ( 
[products] => Array ( 
        [0] => Array ( 
            [title] => Tropika
            [id] => 21645 
            [created_at] => 2016-03-14T19:04:19Z 
            [updated_at] => 2016-05-03T17:52:59Z 
            [type] => variable
            ...
            [variations] => Array ( 
                [0] => Array ( 
                    [id] => 21648 
                    [created_at] => 2016-03-14T19:04:19Z
                    ...
                    [attributes] => Array ( 
                        [0] => Array ( 
                            [name] => nicotine content 
                            [slug] => nicotine-content 
                            [option] => 12 )
                        ...
                    ...
                [1] => array (
                    ...
                ...
            ...
        ...
```

I currently parse/flip this into the following "buffer array"

```
Array ( 
    [Tropika] => Array ( 
        [0] => 21645 // parent product id
        [21648] => Array ( [12] => nicotine content [30ml] => volume )
        ...
    ...
```

The reason I parse it as above is so I can loop with a couple isset
statements for the title and attributes. This lets me quickly go through a
user provided csv file and check for matches.

The issue I have is taking the resulting matches and getting an array
that matches the following to send back to the REST API handling
product updates.

```
$data = [
    'products' => [
        [
            'id' => 604,
            'variations' => [
                [
                    'id' => 609,
                    'regular_price' => '29.99'
                ],
                [
                    'id' => 611,
                    'regular_price' => '29.99'
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
];
```

I'm constrained to PHP 5.3.28 The question specifically is this:
I can flip the array / array_push and this lets me add the matching
variations no problem. But how can I do that without also adding a new
product element each time (the variations must be a sub-array of their
parent product.)

Right now I add the parent product 8 times with 1 variation in each, I need
to reverse those numbers so it's 1 product with it's variation as children.

At first I thought I could add the variation as children by using the
product id as the key for the products array (flipping it later) but that didn't quite meet the spec for sending bulk product data back either.

This is the block (within an !feof while) that's responsible for getting
matches based on title and 2 variations.

```
            if (isset($rjw_buffer[$rjw_csv[0]]))    // If Title Matches
            {

                foreach($rjw_buffer[$rjw_csv[0]] as $buff_id => $buff_var)  // Parse Variations for Matches.
                {
                    if (isset($buff_var[$rjw_variant[0]]))      // If one matches, test the other.
                    {
                        if (isset($buff_var[$rjw_variant[1]]))  //  If both match, update product.
                        {
                            $rjw_data['products'][$rjw_buffer[$rjw_csv[0]][0]] = array(
                                'id' => $rjw_buffer[$rjw_csv[0]][0],
                                'variations' => array());
                            array_push($rjw_data['products'][$rjw_buffer[$rjw_csv[0]][0]]['variations'],
                                array(
                                    'id' => $buff_id,
                                    'stock_quantity' => $rjw_csv[5],
                                    'regular_price' => $rjw_csv[9]));

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

I then put the array through array_values. Right now I'm producing

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( 
        [21638] => Array ( 
            [id] => 21638 
            [variations] => Array ( 
                [0] => Array ( 
                    [id] => 21819 
                    [stock_quantity] => 8.00 
                    [regular_price] => 29.99 ) ) ) 
        [21645] => Array ( 
            [id] => 21645 
            [variations] => Array ( 
                [0] => Array ( 
                    [id] => 21648 
                    [stock_quantity] => 8.00 
                    [regular_price] => 29.99 
                ) 
            ) 
        ) 
    )
)
```

which is so close. There should be 8 variations though, and match
the spec.

Comment: where does the product id come from? I don't see it in your first array.

Comment: Can you clarify this: Are you looking to create a better temporary array from your existing loop? Or are you looking for another loop to create another temporary array from which to form your JSON response?

Comment: I'm attempting to form a JSON response from the data that follows the spec provided. the product id is within the array where [title] is.

Comment: Everyone disappeared :/ Question doesn't get much clearer. No matter what I do I can't seem to get a formatted array from formatted data.

Answer (score 0):

Alright I figured it out.

```
                    if (isset($buff_var[$rjw_variant[0]]))      // If one matches, test the other.
                    {
                        if (isset($buff_var[$rjw_variant[1]]))  //  If both match, update product.
                        {
                            // data[parentid]['id'] = parentid.
                            $rjw_data[$rjw_buffer[$rjw_csv[0]][0]]['id'] = $rjw_buffer[$rjw_csv[0]][0];
                            $rjw_data[$rjw_buffer[$rjw_csv[0]][0]]['title'] = $rjw_csv[0];

                            // Make sure variations is an array so array_push works.
                            if(!isset($rjw_data[$rjw_buffer[$rjw_csv[0]][0]]['variations']))
                                $rjw_data[$rjw_buffer[$rjw_csv[0]][0]]['variations'] = array();
                            // data[parentid]['variations'] new array with info.
                            array_push($rjw_data[$rjw_buffer[$rjw_csv[0]][0]]['variations'],array(
                                'id' => $buff_id,
                                'stock_quantity' => $rjw_csv[5],
                                'regular_price' => $rjw_csv[9])
                            );
                        }   // MATCH LOOP
                    }
```

...

```
$rjw_data = array('products' => array_values($rjw_data));
```

Makes the previous array match the spec for sending data (ie)

```
Array (
    'products' => array(
        array(
            'id' = 21648
            'variations' => array(
                array(
                    'id' = 21638
                    'stock_quantity' = 12.00
                    )
                array(
                    ...
                    )
            )
        )
        array(
            'id' = 21648
            'variations' = array(
                array(
                    ...
                )
            )
        )
        ...
    )
)
```